# how to create a view like a cell with disclosure accessory button?

Tags: iphone

I want to pop up a view when user touch on the screen,it is just like a tableview cell with disclosure accessory button.It has text showing message and when the user press the accessory button,it will take some action.

I have seen a similar example in iphone cookbook, it create a UICalloutView:UIControl,
but it seems that it uses some private API.

can anyone tell me how to achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's probably private. You could printScrn the accessory and add it as a resource to your project, and use it as an image.

Comment: well, the problem is how to catch the user touching the accessory?

Comment: Create the accessory as a UIImageView, and add it to your view. Next, when a touch is being detected you could check whether the touched view is your accessory view via [touch view] or use the CGRectContainsPoint method, to see if the touch's location is inside the accessory UIImageView.

Hope that helps,
~ Natanavra.